# Two dialog boxes on one page and enabling checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, dialog

I am creating a form with a checkbox that says "Agree to Code of Conduct and Guidelines", in which 'Code of Conduct' and 'Guidelines' are hyperlinks that open dialog boxes. However, I do not want this checkbox to be enabled (aka, the user cannot click on the checkbox) until they have clicked both hyperlinks.

Code is shown here:

```
<input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" placeholder="CodeofConduct" name="coc" ref={register({ required: true })} /><span>Agree to <a id="link1" className="coc" onClick={handleClickOpen('paper')}>Code of Conduct</a> and <a id="link2" className="guideline" onClick={handleClickOpen('paper')}>Guidelines</a></span>

{errors.coc && errors.coc.type === "required" && <span className="error">You must agree to the Code of Conduct and Guidelines.</span>}

<Dialog id="link1"
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  scroll={scroll}>
  <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">Code of Conduct: Our Values</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent dividers={scroll === 'paper'}>
    ... //Dialog content
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>

<Dialog id="link2"
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  scroll={scroll}>
  <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">Code of Conduct: Our Values</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent dividers={scroll === 'paper'}>
    ... //Dialog content
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

I need a function to keep track of whether those two hyperlinks have been clicked, and ensure that the appropriate dialog boxes are appearing when each link is clicked on. Right now, only the dialog content labeled as `link2` is showing in both of my dialog boxes. Could someone please show me how to show two dialog boxes on the same page, as well as only enable the checkbox alongside them when both of these links are clicked?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a solution for checking if two links have been clicked!

You can try to listen whether a link has been clicked or not by using a script.

```
<a id="link1" target="_blank" href="https://google.com/">Link 1</a> <br>
<a id="link2" target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com">Link 2</a>
```

.

```
<script>
  var link1;   // Create a boolean to save if link1 has been clicked
  var link2;   // Create a boolean to save if link2 has been clicked

  document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click", link1_true, true);   // Listen click of element with id "link1" 
  document.getElementById("link2").addEventListener("click", link2_true, true);   // Listen click of element with id "link2" 

  function link1_true() {   // Change the state of the variable to true
    link1 = true;           // Set the variable "link2" to true to save that it has been clicked
    check_link_state()      // Run "check_link_state" function to check if both links have been clicked
  }

  function link2_true() {   // Change the state of the variable to true
    link2 = true;           // Set the variable "link2" to true to save that it has been clicked
    check_link_state()      // Run "check_link_state" function to check if both links have been clicked
  }

  function check_link_state() {
    if ((link1 == true) && (link2 == true)) {   // Check if both links have been clicked
      alert("Both links have been clicked!");  
      // Put here the code to execute if both links have been clicked
    }
  }
</script>
```